# how to map a file by a single character

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm just so sick of typing ***source ~/.vimrc*** all the time, for entering the "~/.vimrc" I have to move my fingers a lot. Is there a way that I could map ~/.vimrc into a single letter or a sign. For example ***source %*** instead of ***source ~/.vimrc***

AkA I would like to use **%** to represent **~/.vimrc**

Thanks

Comment: As it appends `%` refers to the file currently being edited in `vim`. So if you're editing `~/.vimrc`, `:source %` will source it.

Comment: At a shell prompt, or within vim?

Comment: @JeffSchaller within vim Thanks for point that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:abbreviate

```
:ab % ~/.vimrc
```

I would recommend you to use another character in stead of %

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is good. A few "enhancements"...

The Vim environment variable `$MYVIMRC` contains the path to whatever file was actually sourced as your vimrc so it's a convenient and portable way to express `~/.vimrc`...might want to use that in the abbreviation.

If you're really sick of typing then you could avoid `:source`, too (not counting the fact that you only have to type `:so`):

```
nnoremap <C-S> :so $MYVRIMC<CR>
```

With this you can load your vimrc by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and you don't even have to leave Normal mode. (`<C-S>` is an example...replace it with whatever unused key(s) you want.)

Comment: @B Layer awesome!